# Clickonce publishing from Visual Studio 2013 command-line with MSBuild cannot find SignTool.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, clickonce, signtool

I have a build-script which I've been using for ages now, and worked fine in all previous VS versions up to 2012. After migrating to 2013 the build script fails to sign the ClickOnce manifest at the end of the build process, and complains about not finding SignTool.exe.

- I'm running a Windows 8.1 on a 64 bit machine, installed the full
  Visual Studio 2013. I tried to reinstall the Windows SDK for 8.1, but
  still no success.
- The publish process successfully signs the manifest when I run the
  publish inside Visual Studio.
- I've searched for `signtool.exe` and the only hit was in `C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\bin`

I'm not actuallz too good at MSBuild stuff, so I have no clue what could I try or how could I show MSBuild that it should find that tool there.

If anyone had such experience please give me some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that **I've used the X64 version of the Visual Studio Commnad Line, instead of the X86**. It's possible that it has to match with my projects target platform, because it's x86. Building and signing from the x86 commandline is working without any errors.

Hope this can help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is a "can't locate xxx" variety of error, perhaps there is a path messed up.  In the [new version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx) of MSBuild that comes with VS.NET 2013 it looks like some paths were changed.  Maybe you have a relative path in a build file that is now going to have to be updated?

Going to need your full build files to provide any more insight.

Comment: Thanks for tha answer. I don't actually have a "build file". I'm using a simple bat file with one command: calling msbuild.exe with my project with /t:publish and with some parameters like configuration, platform, updateurl, etc. I'm not redefining any path or so in the parameters, and not in my project file either. Actually I've searched my project file for some kind of "Path" variable definition, but couldn't find any. Will look around again when I get there today.